# how to insert multiple row from gridview in database

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim invoiceclass As New InvoiceClass()
    Dim invoicedb As New DbInvoiceClass()
    invoiceclass.CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text
    invoiceclass.DateInvoice = txtDate.Text
    invoiceclass.NetTotal = txtNetTotal.Text
    invoicedb.InsertInvoice(invoiceclass)
    Dim ID As Integer


    Dim con As New SqlConnection(DbConnectionClass.ConnectionStringName)


    con.Open()
    If con.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then

        Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Code) FROM InvoiceTB", con)
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ID = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar())


        For Each item As GridViewRow In gvrview.Rows

            'Modified according your table Definition 
            Dim statment As String = String.Format("insert into  InvoiceItem ( ProductName,Price, Quantity, Total,CodeInvoice ) values ('{0}',{1},{2},{3},{4} )", item.Cells(1).Text, item.Cells(2).Text, item.Cells(3).Text, ID.ToString())
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(statment, con)

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()

            cmd.Dispose()
        Next




    End If
    con.Close()


End Sub
```

it gave me this error ....Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are starting at cell index 1 which is actually the second column of your gridview.

```
Column2 = item.Cells(1).Text
Column3 = item.Cells(2).Text
Column4 = item.Cells(3).Text
```

If you do not have a column4 and you are trying to return item.Cells(3).Text you are going to get an exception.

If my assumptions are correct and you only have 3 columns in your gridview then replace the line with this one and you will be all set.

```
Dim statment As String = String.Format("insert into  InvoiceItem ( ProductName,Price, Quantity, Total,CodeInvoice ) values ('{0}',{1},{2},{3},{4} )", item.Cells(0).Text, item.Cells(1).Text, item.Cells(2).Text, ID.ToString())
```